# Calculate running total of XML attribute value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, cumulative-sum

For each **CoordGeom** segment (Line, Curve or Spiral) inside `/LandXML/Alignments/Alignment/CoordGeom`, I'm trying to calculate the **running total** for @length in the following SQL query:

https://dbfiddle.uk/GQRK6TCk

```
Declare @xml XML = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LandXML xmlns="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.1 http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.1/LandXML-1.1.xsd" date="2007-10-20" time="17:22:09" version="1.1" language="English" readOnly="false">
    <Units>
        <Imperial areaUnit="squareFoot" linearUnit="foot" volumeUnit="cubicYard" temperatureUnit="fahrenheit" pressureUnit="inchHG" diameterUnit="inch" angularUnit="decimal degrees" directionUnit="decimal degrees"></Imperial>
    </Units>
    <CoordinateSystem desc="HARN (HPGN) Florida State Planes, East Zone, US Foot" ogcWktCode="PROJCS[&quot;FLHP-EF&quot;,GEOGCS[&quot;LL-HPGN&quot;,DATUM[&quot;HPGN&quot;,SPHEROID[&quot;GRS1980&quot;,6378137.000,298.25722210]],PRIMEM[&quot;Greenwich&quot;,0],UNIT[&quot;Degree&quot;,0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION[&quot;Transverse_Mercator&quot;],PARAMETER[&quot;false_easting&quot;,656166.667],PARAMETER[&quot;false_northing&quot;,0.000],PARAMETER[&quot;scale_factor&quot;,0.999941176471],PARAMETER[&quot;central_meridian&quot;,-81.00000000000000],PARAMETER[&quot;latitude_of_origin&quot;,24.33333333333333],UNIT[&quot;Foot_US&quot;,0.30480060960122]]" horizontalDatum="HPGN" horizontalCoordinateSystemName="FLHP-EF" fileLocation="AutoCAD Map Zone Name"></CoordinateSystem>
    <Project name="C:\Documents and Settings\JorgeK\Desktop\CURRENT\UCF\SR-DGN-PROJ\UCF-ARBORETUM\dwg\UCF-ARB-FDGN.dwg"></Project>
    <Application name="AutoCAD Civil 3D" desc="Civil 3D" manufacturer="Autodesk, Inc." version="2008" manufacturerURL="www.autodesk.com/civil" timeStamp="2007-10-20T17:22:09"></Application>
    <Alignments name="">
        <Alignment name="AL-1" length="54.055248541569" staStart="1000." desc="">
            <CoordGeom>
                <Line dir="332.184029560865" length="8.864727370067">
                    <Start>1550921.5827274956 592831.84063415369</Start>
                    <End>1550917.4461515071 592839.68105062458</End>
                </Line>
                <Spiral length="10." radiusEnd="30." radiusStart="INF" rot="cw" spiType="clothoid" theta="9.549296585514" totalY="0.554454236563" totalX="9.972257921783" tanLong="6.676392709492" tanShort="3.342176984846">
                    <Start>1550917.4461515071 592839.68105062458</Start>
                    <PI>1550914.3307244433 592845.58599368203</PI>
                    <End>1550912.3023774354 592848.24229678721</End>
                </Spiral>
                <Curve rot="cw" chord="1.295497212228" crvType="arc" delta="2.474409707229" dirEnd="320.160323270288" dirStart="322.634732977518" external="0.006995416978" length="1.295597893068" midOrd="0.006993786163" radius="30.000000000797" tangent="0.6478996485">
                    <Start>1550912.3023774354 592848.24229678733</Start>
                    <Center>1550888.4588973736 592830.03547228139</Center>
                    <End>1550911.494099478 592849.25471951056</End>
                    <PI>1550911.9091709286 592848.7572361991</PI>
                </Curve>
                <Spiral length="10." radiusEnd="INF" radiusStart="30." rot="cw" spiType="clothoid" theta="9.549296585514" totalY="0.554454236563" totalX="9.972257921783" tanLong="6.676392709492" tanShort="3.342176984846">
                    <Start>1550911.494099478 592849.25471951056</Start>
                    <PI>1550909.3529630154 592851.82097600971</PI>
                    <End>1550904.2846047955 592856.16677665606</End>
                </Spiral>
                <Line dir="310.611026682892" length="7.019159649992">
                    <Start>1550904.2846047955 592856.16677665606</Start>
                    <End>1550898.9560374692 592860.73569036077</End>
                </Line>
                <Line dir="300.875832153876" length="16.875763628442">
                    <Start>1550898.9560374692 592860.73569036077</Start>
                    <End>1550884.4718826693 592869.39598237514</End>
                </Line>
            </CoordGeom>
        </Alignment>
        <Alignment name="AL-2" length="103.912591379321" staStart="8000." desc="">
            <CoordGeom>
                <Line dir="17.57965069973" length="21.307738926737">
                    <Start>1550912.0899307244 592848.51720009069</Start>
                    <End>1550918.5255355434 592868.82982495264</End>
                </Line>
                <Spiral length="10." radiusEnd="33.501322221944" radiusStart="INF" rot="cw" spiType="clothoid" theta="8.551271369754" totalY="0.496701819232" totalX="9.977748041186" tanLong="6.674461833374" tanShort="3.340421001603">
                    <Start>1550918.5255355434 592868.82982495264</Start>
                    <PI>1550920.5414324952 592875.19257712457</PI>
                    <End>1550921.0656232478 592878.49161169864</End>
                </Spiral>
                <Line dir="9.028379326447" length="1.811956496263">
                    <Start>1550921.0656232478 592878.49161169864</Start>
                    <End>1550921.3499620936 592880.28111938655</End>
                </Line>
                <Spiral length="10." radiusEnd="36.82437422537" radiusStart="INF" rot="cw" spiType="clothoid" theta="7.779599887078" totalY="0.452003113127" totalX="9.981579620353" tanLong="6.673116056263" tanShort="3.339197204298">
                    <Start>1550921.3499620936 592880.28111938655</Start>
                    <PI>1550922.3971320367 592886.8715613574</PI>
                    <End>1550922.4699049771 592890.20996455965</End>
                </Spiral>
                <Line dir="1.248779438117" length="33.289436906511">
                    <Start>1550922.4699049771 592890.20996455965</Start>
                    <End>1550923.1954012257 592923.49149494432</End>
                </Line>
                <Line dir="2.196010733584" length="3.17722982984">
                    <Start>1550923.1954012257 592923.49149494432</Start>
                    <End>1550923.3171470633 592926.66639137454</End>
                </Line>
                <Spiral length="10." radiusEnd="30." radiusStart="INF" rot="cw" spiType="clothoid" theta="9.549296585514" totalY="0.554454236563" totalX="9.972257921783" tanLong="6.676392709492" tanShort="3.342176984846">
                    <Start>1550923.3171470633 592926.66639137454</Start>
                    <PI>1550923.5729746986 592933.3378822516</PI>
                    <End>1550923.145219343 592936.65257124556</End>
                </Spiral>
                <Curve rot="cw" chord="0.382669369498" crvType="arc" delta="0.730849615493" dirEnd="351.915864559344" dirStart="352.646714174837" external="0.000610167975" length="0.382671963827" midOrd="0.000610155565" radius="30.000000000672" tangent="0.191338576292">
                    <Start>1550923.145219343 592936.65257124568</Start>
                    <Center>1550893.3919440852 592932.81296039547</Center>
                    <End>1550923.0938230981 592937.03177339805</End>
                    <PI>1550923.1207304872 592936.84233622323</PI>
                </Curve>
                <Spiral length="10." radiusEnd="INF" radiusStart="30." rot="cw" spiType="clothoid" theta="9.549296585514" totalY="0.554454236563" totalX="9.972257921783" tanLong="6.676392709492" tanShort="3.342176984846">
                    <Start>1550923.0938230979 592937.03177339805</Start>
                    <PI>1550922.6238228632 592940.34073661186</PI>
                    <End>1550920.6013693318 592946.70343415416</End>
                </Spiral>
                <Line dir="342.366567947968" length="3.943557256143">
                    <Start>1550920.6013693318 592946.70343415416</Start>
                    <End>1550919.4067632062 592950.46169971651</End>
                </Line>
            </CoordGeom>
        </Alignment>
    </Alignments>
</LandXML>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.1')
SELECT
   T.record.value('(../../@name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(32)') as AlignmentName,
   T.record.value('(../../@length)[1]', 'FLOAT') as AlignmentLength,
   T.record.value('(../../@staStart)[1]', 'FLOAT') as AlignmentStartM,
   T.record.value('let $i := . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int') as SegmentNum,
   T.record.value('local-name(.[1])', 'VARCHAR(32)') as SegmentType,
   T.record.value('@length[1]', 'FLOAT') as SegmentLength,
   T.record.value('sum(for $x in . return $x/@length)', 'float') as SegmentStartM,
   T.record.value('sum(for $x in . return $x/@length)', 'float') as SegmentEndM
FROM @xml.nodes('LandXML/Alignments/Alignment/CoordGeom/*') AS T(record);
```

The goal is to get `SegmentStartM` to equal the **sum of all the previous @length attribute values** in a particular alignment.

```
   T.record.value('sum(for $x in . return $x/@length)', 'float') as SegmentStartM
```

`SegmentEndM` would then equal the **sum of all the previous @length attribute values plus the current @length**.

```
   T.record.value('sum(for $x in . return $x/@length)', 'float') as SegmentEndM
```

I've been banging my head on this for days, feel like I've tried everything but just not getting it:

```
T.record.value('let $i := . return count(../*[@length << $i]) + ../../@staStart[1]', 'float') as SegmentStartM,

T.record.value('let $i := . return count(../*[. << $i]) + ../../@staStart[1]', 'float') as SegmentStartM,

T.record.value('let $i := @length[1] return count(../*[. << $i]) + ../../@staStart[1]', 'float') as SegmentStartM,

T.record.value('let $i := . let $sum := sum(@length[$i]) return $sum', 'FLOAT') as SegmentStartM,

T.record.value('let $i := (1,2,3,4) let $sum := sum($i) return $sum', 'FLOAT') as SegmentStartM,

T.record.value('let $s := . for $i in $s return sum(@length[$i and $s])', 'float') as SegmentStartM,

T.record.value('let $s := . for $i in $s return sum(@length[$i])', 'float') as SegmentStartM,

T.record.value('let $s := . for $i in $s return sum(@length[$i and $s])', 'float') as SegmentStartM,

T.record.value('for $pos in . return sum(@length[$pos])', 'float') as SegmentStartM,

T.record.value('let $i := . return sum(for $x in $i return @length[. << $x])', 'float') as SegmentStartM,

T.record.value('let $i := . return sum(@length[. << $i])', 'float') as SegmentStartM,

T.record.value('let $i := . for $s in (@length[. << $i]) return sum($s)', 'float') as SegmentStartM,

T.record.value('let $i := . for $s in (../*[. << $i]) return sum(@length[$s])', 'float') as SegmentStartM,

T.record.value('let $i := . for $x in ../*[. << $i] return @length[$x]', 'float') as SegmentStartM,
```

Anyone know how to caculate the running total of an attribute value (@length) for the current node plus all previous nodes within the same alignment?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: ##3-4 are missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the `CoordGeom` selection into an `APPLY` and just calculate the running sum over that, which simplifies it a lot. It means you don't need to use the complex and slow `count(. <<` hack to get a row-number, as you can just use the normal `ROW_NUMBER` function.

There are also other simplifications:

- Instead of using the rather slow `//` axis, select directly from each level of the XML using separate `.nodes` functions.
- There is no need for `[1]` on attributes or `local-name` as they are guaranteed to return one value.
- Use `ROW UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` for running sum. It's faster and in some cases more accurate.
- Consider using `decimal` instead of `float` for better accuracy.

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.1')
SELECT
   X1.alignment.value('@name', 'VARCHAR(32)') as AlignmentName,
   X1.alignment.value('@length', 'FLOAT') as AlignmentLength,
   X1.alignment.value('@staStart', 'FLOAT') as AlignmentStartM,
   cg.SegmentNum,
   cg.SegmentType,
   cg.SegmentLength,
   cg.SegmentStartM,
   cg.SegmentEndM,
   cg.RunningTotalLength
FROM @xml.nodes('LandXML/Alignments/Alignment') X1(alignment)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as SegmentNum,
      T.record.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(32)') as SegmentType,
      T.record.value('@length', 'FLOAT') as SegmentLength,
      T.record.value('sum(*/@length)', 'float') as SegmentStartM,
      T.record.value('sum(*/@length)', 'float') as SegmentEndM,
      SUM(T.record.value('@length', 'FLOAT')) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS RunningTotalLength
  FROM X1.alignment.nodes('CoordGeom/*') AS T(record)
) cg;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Lrl7TX6F)

Note that you cannot select the `.nodes` value directly out of a subquery, you must select values from it using `.value`.

Comment: Is the node order really guaranteed here?

Comment: No, but it's not really possible for there to be anything different due to the way the compiler works.

Comment: Alright, that's fair i guess, i'm usually not fan of undefined sorts though. Btw, Aaron taught me one can use ORDER BY @@SPID instead of (SELECT 1)

Comment: Probably right, although I'm generally blaise about row-numbers on internal TVFs because I don't believe there is any chance of it coming back in the wrong order (as long as there are no joins or other reason to sort it, so keep it in a single subquery).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you just need a windowed function which sums SegmentLength partitioned by AlignmentName and Ordered by SegementNum?

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.1')
SELECT
   T.record.value('(../../@name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(32)') as AlignmentName,
   T.record.value('(../../@length)[1]', 'FLOAT') as AlignmentLength,
   T.record.value('(../../@staStart)[1]', 'FLOAT') as AlignmentStartM,
   T.record.value('let $i := . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int') as SegmentNum,
   T.record.value('local-name(.[1])', 'VARCHAR(32)') as SegmentType,
   T.record.value('@length[1]', 'FLOAT') as SegmentLength,
   T.record.value('sum(for $x in . return $x/@length)', 'float') as SegmentStartM,
   T.record.value('sum(for $x in . return $x/@length)', 'float') as SegmentEndM,
   SUM(T.record.value('@length[1]', 'FLOAT')) OVER (PARTITION BY T.record.value('(../../@name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(32)') ORDER BY T.record.value('let $i := . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int')) AS RunningTotalLength
FROM @xml.nodes('LandXML/Alignments/Alignment/CoordGeom/*') AS T(record);
```

| AlignmentName | AlignmentLength | AlignmentStartM | SegmentNum | SegmentType | SegmentLength | SegmentStartM | SegmentEndM | RunningTotalLength |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AL-1 | 54.055248541569 | 1000 | 1 | Line | 8.864727370067 | 8.864727370067 | 8.864727370067 | 8.864727370067 |
| AL-1 | 54.055248541569 | 1000 | 2 | Spiral | 10 | 10 | 10 | 18.864727370067 |
| AL-1 | 54.055248541569 | 1000 | 3 | Curve | 1.295597893068 | 1.295597893068 | 1.295597893068 | 20.160325263135 |
| AL-1 | 54.055248541569 | 1000 | 4 | Spiral | 10 | 10 | 10 | 30.160325263135 |
| AL-1 | 54.055248541569 | 1000 | 5 | Line | 7.019159649992 | 7.019159649992 | 7.019159649992 | 37.179484913127 |
| AL-1 | 54.055248541569 | 1000 | 6 | Line | 16.875763628442 | 16.875763628442 | 16.875763628442 | 54.055248541569 |
| AL-2 | 103.912591379321 | 8000 | 1 | Line | 21.307738926737 | 21.307738926737 | 21.307738926737 | 21.307738926737 |
| AL-2 | 103.912591379321 | 8000 | 2 | Spiral | 10 | 10 | 10 | 31.307738926737 |
| AL-2 | 103.912591379321 | 8000 | 3 | Line | 1.811956496263 | 1.811956496263 | 1.811956496263 | 33.119695423 |
| AL-2 | 103.912591379321 | 8000 | 4 | Spiral | 10 | 10 | 10 | 43.119695423 |
| AL-2 | 103.912591379321 | 8000 | 5 | Line | 33.289436906511 | 33.289436906511 | 33.289436906511 | 76.409132329511 |
| AL-2 | 103.912591379321 | 8000 | 6 | Line | 3.17722982984 | 3.17722982984 | 3.17722982984 | 79.586362159351 |
| AL-2 | 103.912591379321 | 8000 | 7 | Spiral | 10 | 10 | 10 | 89.586362159351 |
| AL-2 | 103.912591379321 | 8000 | 8 | Curve | 0.382671963827 | 0.382671963827 | 0.382671963827 | 89.969034123178 |
| AL-2 | 103.912591379321 | 8000 | 9 | Spiral | 10 | 10 | 10 | 99.969034123178 |
| AL-2 | 103.912591379321 | 8000 | 10 | Line | 3.943557256143 | 3.943557256143 | 3.943557256143 | 103.912591379321 |

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of the old hated OPENXML, so here's a potential solution to your problem:

```sql
-- @xml incorporated by defauilt from your code
declare @DocHandle int

DECLARE @xmlns nvarchar(max)
SET @xmlns = '<root xmlns:h="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.1 http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.1/LandXML-1.1.xsd" date="2007-10-20" time="17:22:09" version="1.1" language="English" readOnly="false"/>'

BEGIN TRY

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @xml, @xmlns;

SELECT  Alignment
,   id
,   length
,   SUM(length) OVER(PARTITION BY parentIDNO ORDER BY id) AS aggLength
,   comment AS parent
,   ParentIDNO
FROM OPENXML (@DocHandle, 'h:LandXML/h:Alignments/h:Alignment/h:CoordGeom/*') with (
        length numeric(19,12) '@length'
    ,   id int '@mp:id'
    ,   Alignment nvarchar(max) '../../@name'
    ,   parentIDNo int '@mp:parentid'
    ,   comment nvarchar(max) '@mp:xmltext'
) x;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dm_exec_xml_handles (@@spid) WHERE document_id  = @DocHandle)
    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocHandle;

THROW;

END CATCH;

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocHandle;
```

The upside of `OPENXML` is that it returns positional IDs of elements which simplifies this kind of stuff.
`@mp:id` is the magic id of each element ordered, and `@mp:parentid` contains the parent id, which is used to partition by.

Rest is just a single `SUM OVER PARTITION` running aggregation.

Important when handling openxml is to always close the document handle. Also, due to namespaces, one needs to create a pseudo namespace xml, but otherwise it's pretty smooth

Answer (score 1):

If i'm understanding the question right, maybe something like this?

Basically just store the results in a temp table to make it easier to work with in sql, then join and group on the AlighmentName and SegmentNum

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
     DROP TABLE #temp
 
 Declare @xml XML = '<?xml version="1.0"?> <LandXML
 xmlns="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.1"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.1
 http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.1/LandXML-1.1.xsd"
 date="2007-10-20" time="17:22:09" version="1.1" language="English"
 readOnly="false">
     <Units>
         <Imperial areaUnit="squareFoot" linearUnit="foot" volumeUnit="cubicYard" temperatureUnit="fahrenheit"
 pressureUnit="inchHG" diameterUnit="inch" angularUnit="decimal
 degrees" directionUnit="decimal degrees"></Imperial>
     </Units>
     <CoordinateSystem desc="HARN (HPGN) Florida State Planes, East Zone, US Foot"
 ogcWktCode="PROJCS[&quot;FLHP-EF&quot;,GEOGCS[&quot;LL-HPGN&quot;,DATUM[&quot;HPGN&quot;,SPHEROID[&quot;GRS1980&quot;,6378137.000,298.25722210]],PRIMEM[&quot;Greenwich&quot;,0],UNIT[&quot;Degree&quot;,0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION[&quot;Transverse_Mercator&quot;],PARAMETER[&quot;false_easting&quot;,656166.667],PARAMETER[&quot;false_northing&quot;,0.000],PARAMETER[&quot;scale_factor&quot;,0.999941176471],PARAMETER[&quot;central_meridian&quot;,-81.00000000000000],PARAMETER[&quot;latitude_of_origin&quot;,24.33333333333333],UNIT[&quot;Foot_US&quot;,0.30480060960122]]"
 horizontalDatum="HPGN" horizontalCoordinateSystemName="FLHP-EF"
 fileLocation="AutoCAD Map Zone Name"></CoordinateSystem>
     <Project name="C:\Documents and Settings\JorgeK\Desktop\CURRENT\UCF\SR-DGN-PROJ\UCF-ARBORETUM\dwg\UCF-ARB-FDGN.dwg"></Project>
     <Application name="AutoCAD Civil 3D" desc="Civil 3D" manufacturer="Autodesk, Inc." version="2008"
 manufacturerURL="www.autodesk.com/civil"
 timeStamp="2007-10-20T17:22:09"></Application>
     <Alignments name="">
         <Alignment name="AL-1" length="54.055248541569" staStart="1000." desc="">
             <CoordGeom>
                 <Line dir="332.184029560865" length="8.864727370067">
                     <Start>1550921.5827274956 592831.84063415369</Start>
                     <End>1550917.4461515071 592839.68105062458</End>
                 </Line>
                 <Spiral length="10." radiusEnd="30." radiusStart="INF" rot="cw" spiType="clothoid" theta="9.549296585514"
 totalY="0.554454236563" totalX="9.972257921783"
 tanLong="6.676392709492" tanShort="3.342176984846">
                     <Start>1550917.4461515071 592839.68105062458</Start>
                     <PI>1550914.3307244433 592845.58599368203</PI>
                     <End>1550912.3023774354 592848.24229678721</End>
                 </Spiral>
                 <Curve rot="cw" chord="1.295497212228" crvType="arc" delta="2.474409707229" dirEnd="320.160323270288"
 dirStart="322.634732977518" external="0.006995416978"
 length="1.295597893068" midOrd="0.006993786163"
 radius="30.000000000797" tangent="0.6478996485">
                     <Start>1550912.3023774354 592848.24229678733</Start>
                     <Center>1550888.4588973736 592830.03547228139</Center>
                     <End>1550911.494099478 592849.25471951056</End>
                     <PI>1550911.9091709286 592848.7572361991</PI>
                 </Curve>
                 <Spiral length="10." radiusEnd="INF" radiusStart="30." rot="cw" spiType="clothoid" theta="9.549296585514"
 totalY="0.554454236563" totalX="9.972257921783"
 tanLong="6.676392709492" tanShort="3.342176984846">
                     <Start>1550911.494099478 592849.25471951056</Start>
                     <PI>1550909.3529630154 592851.82097600971</PI>
                     <End>1550904.2846047955 592856.16677665606</End>
                 </Spiral>
                 <Line dir="310.611026682892" length="7.019159649992">
                     <Start>1550904.2846047955 592856.16677665606</Start>
                     <End>1550898.9560374692 592860.73569036077</End>
                 </Line>
                 <Line dir="300.875832153876" length="16.875763628442">
                     <Start>1550898.9560374692 592860.73569036077</Start>
                     <End>1550884.4718826693 592869.39598237514</End>
                 </Line>
             </CoordGeom>
         </Alignment>
         <Alignment name="AL-2" length="103.912591379321" staStart="8000." desc="">
             <CoordGeom>
                 <Line dir="17.57965069973" length="21.307738926737">
                     <Start>1550912.0899307244 592848.51720009069</Start>
                     <End>1550918.5255355434 592868.82982495264</End>
                 </Line>
                 <Spiral length="10." radiusEnd="33.501322221944" radiusStart="INF" rot="cw" spiType="clothoid" theta="8.551271369754"
 totalY="0.496701819232" totalX="9.977748041186"
 tanLong="6.674461833374" tanShort="3.340421001603">
                     <Start>1550918.5255355434 592868.82982495264</Start>
                     <PI>1550920.5414324952 592875.19257712457</PI>
                     <End>1550921.0656232478 592878.49161169864</End>
                 </Spiral>
                 <Line dir="9.028379326447" length="1.811956496263">
                     <Start>1550921.0656232478 592878.49161169864</Start>
                     <End>1550921.3499620936 592880.28111938655</End>
                 </Line>
                 <Spiral length="10." radiusEnd="36.82437422537" radiusStart="INF" rot="cw" spiType="clothoid" theta="7.779599887078"
 totalY="0.452003113127" totalX="9.981579620353"
 tanLong="6.673116056263" tanShort="3.339197204298">
                     <Start>1550921.3499620936 592880.28111938655</Start>
                     <PI>1550922.3971320367 592886.8715613574</PI>
                     <End>1550922.4699049771 592890.20996455965</End>
                 </Spiral>
                 <Line dir="1.248779438117" length="33.289436906511">
                     <Start>1550922.4699049771 592890.20996455965</Start>
                     <End>1550923.1954012257 592923.49149494432</End>
                 </Line>
                 <Line dir="2.196010733584" length="3.17722982984">
                     <Start>1550923.1954012257 592923.49149494432</Start>
                     <End>1550923.3171470633 592926.66639137454</End>
                 </Line>
                 <Spiral length="10." radiusEnd="30." radiusStart="INF" rot="cw" spiType="clothoid" theta="9.549296585514"
 totalY="0.554454236563" totalX="9.972257921783"
 tanLong="6.676392709492" tanShort="3.342176984846">
                     <Start>1550923.3171470633 592926.66639137454</Start>
                     <PI>1550923.5729746986 592933.3378822516</PI>
                     <End>1550923.145219343 592936.65257124556</End>
                 </Spiral>
                 <Curve rot="cw" chord="0.382669369498" crvType="arc" delta="0.730849615493" dirEnd="351.915864559344"
 dirStart="352.646714174837" external="0.000610167975"
 length="0.382671963827" midOrd="0.000610155565"
 radius="30.000000000672" tangent="0.191338576292">
                     <Start>1550923.145219343 592936.65257124568</Start>
                     <Center>1550893.3919440852 592932.81296039547</Center>
                     <End>1550923.0938230981 592937.03177339805</End>
                     <PI>1550923.1207304872 592936.84233622323</PI>
                 </Curve>
                 <Spiral length="10." radiusEnd="INF" radiusStart="30." rot="cw" spiType="clothoid" theta="9.549296585514"
 totalY="0.554454236563" totalX="9.972257921783"
 tanLong="6.676392709492" tanShort="3.342176984846">
                     <Start>1550923.0938230979 592937.03177339805</Start>
                     <PI>1550922.6238228632 592940.34073661186</PI>
                     <End>1550920.6013693318 592946.70343415416</End>
                 </Spiral>
                 <Line dir="342.366567947968" length="3.943557256143">
                     <Start>1550920.6013693318 592946.70343415416</Start>
                     <End>1550919.4067632062 592950.46169971651</End>
                 </Line>
             </CoordGeom>
         </Alignment>
     </Alignments> </LandXML>';
 
 WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT
 'http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.1') SELECT   
 T.record.value('(../../@name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(32)') as AlignmentName,   
 T.record.value('(../../@length)[1]', 'FLOAT') as AlignmentLength,   
 T.record.value('(../../@staStart)[1]', 'FLOAT') as AlignmentStartM,   
 T.record.value('let $i := . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int')
 as SegmentNum,    T.record.value('local-name(.[1])', 'VARCHAR(32)') as
 SegmentType,    T.record.value('@length[1]', 'FLOAT') as
 SegmentLength,    T.record.value('sum(for $x in . return $x/@length)',
 'float') as SegmentStartM,    T.record.value('sum(for $x in . return
 $x/@length)', 'float') as SegmentEndM INTO #temp FROM
 @xml.nodes('LandXML/Alignments/Alignment/CoordGeom/*') AS T(record)
 order by AlignmentName, SegmentNum
 
 
 select  t1.AlignmentName 
 , t1.AlignmentLength 
 , t1.AlignmentStartM 
 , t1.SegmentNum 
 , t1.SegmentType 
 , t1.SegmentLength 
 , IsNull(sum(tstart.segmentLength),0) as SegmentStartM 
 , Isnull(sum(tstart.segmentLength), 0) + t1.SegmentLength as SegmentEndM
 from #temp t1  
 left join #temp tstart on t1.AlignmentName = tstart.AlignmentName and t1.SegmentNum > tstart.SegmentNum 
 group by
 t1.AlignmentName , t1.AlignmentLength , t1.AlignmentStartM ,
 t1.SegmentNum , t1.SegmentType , t1.SegmentLength 
 order by t1.AlignmentName, t1.SegmentNum
```